Scikit-learn PR: "Upload to Codecov" Failed
Good afternoon,
When I did a Pull Request to scikit-learn, it failed the pipeline "Linux pymin_conda_defaults_openblas" "Upload to Codecov" section, with error:
[2024-04-05T12:52:37.829Z] ['error'] There was an error running the uploader: Error uploading to https://codecov.io: Error: There was an error fetching the storage URL during POST: 503 - upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection failure
[2024-04-05T12:52:37.829Z] ['verbose'] The error stack is: Error: Error uploading to https://codecov.io: Error: There was an error fetching the storage URL during POST: 503 - upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection failure at main (/snapshot/repo/dist/src/index.js) at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) [2024-04-05T12:52:37.829Z] ['verbose'] End of uploader: 474 milliseconds
##[error]Bash exited with code '255'.
Everyting else passed, any idea of what could've caused the fail?

For anyone that encounters this error, it was a Codecov server error. Do an empty commit and the checks will succeed.
